# How to automaic sum the total number of pen, book and paper sales in excel

Tags: excel

How to automaic sum the total number of pen, book and paper sales in excel
What is the function to type in excel?
[image: l]

Comment: Consider using a pivot table. Otherwise the `SUMIF` function will do what you want.

Comment: @DougGlancy How is being done?. as I not IT savy guy.

Comment: You can use sumif(). Check the excel function help.

Answer (score 0):

So, try this:

[image]

As you posted an image I did not make the effort to type all your data but just sufficient to show that it works.